# Discrete time-series graph with unknown y range

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, timeserieschart

In a discrete time-series graph, I have tried replacing `ax.plot(x,y)`  by `ax.vlines(x,y)`:

- I get the error: `vlines() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ymax'`

However, I cannot know the `ymax` value beforehand. 
How can I avoid this error ?

Should I compute this value by parsing all the data to display ? Is there a way to tell matplotlib to automatically adapt to the data ?

---

Some more details about the graph:

The graph is not accurate, due to the drawing of a continuous curve, whereas my data is instead a distribution of discrete values over time. This is why I want to use `vlines`.

This is the code I create the graph with:

(The exception_time_series object is an object that counts the number of a given exception type at a given time in a program).

```
fig = figure(1) 

for exception_time_series in exceptions_time_series.list_exception_time_series:

    time_values, series_values = exception_time_series.time_values, exception_time_series.series_values

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=True )

    dates = np.array(time_values)
    x = dates 
    y = np.array(series_values)

    ax.plot(x, y, label=exception_time_series.exception) # <=== using plot 
    ax.legend()

show()
```

And that's the graph I'm getting right now:

[image: Rate of SEH-Exception by second]

But I would like to get something of that kind, (that would reflect that it is a irregular distribution over time):

[image: Type of graph that I would like]

Answer (score 2):

looks to me like you want to have a `bar` plot.

`ymax` is the upper limit for `vlines`, `vlines(0, 0, 1)` plots a vertical line at x=0 from y=0 to y=1.

This is a working minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import normal

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = normal(0, 1, 100)
bar_width = (max(x) - min(x))/len(x)

plt.bar(x, y, bar_width, facecolor='black')
plt.show()
```

this is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `ymax` here is not actually the yrange - it's the top value of the vertical lines you want.  To make a vline plot similar to your current plot, I believe you'd want to set the ymin to an array of zeros and ymax to your y values.  If you have negative values in y, you should make ymin and ymax the min/max of 0 and your y array.

```
yz = np.zeros(y.shape)
ymin = np.minimum(yz, y)
ymax = np.maximum(yz, y)

ax.vlines(x, ymin, ymax)
```